# NullPointerException error in findviewbyid in textview in asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

If I want to access a textview in an asynctask from other activity, this textview is undefined in asynctask. What can I do?

for example this code:

```
     private class ParserTask extends
        AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {

    // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(
            String... jsonData) {
          // some code
              }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
        // some code

        *   tvDistanceDuration.setText("distanse:");

            saveLine(points);
        }
}
public void saveLine(final ArrayList<LatLng> points) {

    //// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is   present.

*   findViewById(R.id.button1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //// some code
    }
```

error was occured in * line

Comment: Atleast post code or show us what have you done so far

Comment: your question very unclear

Comment: Don't do anything as you don't have mention any code in your question also.

Comment: i change it;please help now

Comment: please vote up my question . this solved :-(

Answer (score 0):

Pass the activity that holds the view with the textview and to do activity.findViewById()

**Do not do this in doInBackgroundMethod, because you will get a NullPointer exception.

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String> {
private Activity mActivity;

public MyAsyncTask(Activity activity) {
    super();
    this.mActivity = activity;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    mActivity.findViewById(R.id.textview);
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {

    return "ok";
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

}
}
```

Comment: thanks,but if this asynctask was in other asynctask,i have to apply this solution to both of them??

Comment: This is definatelly a solution. Create the new async task by calling something like this:
new MyAsyncTask(mActivity)

Comment: for example:MyAsyncTask1(mActivity){......MyAsyncTask2.execute(mActivity).......}?

Comment: i does this in onPostExecuteMethod not in doInBackgroundMethod.then i get nullpointer beacause this?

Comment: i was try it and i change type of textview to static this seems solved . tnx . hoooraaaa  :-)

Comment: please vote up my question .this solved.thanks a lot

Comment: sorry.My reputation is not enough   :-(